# how to get DB id only after clicking imageButton in listView item with kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, kotlin

i have a customAdapter class and a listView. i made the single_row layout with 3 textviews and one imageButton.
now my question is how can i get the DB id field, only from clicking on the imageButton and ignore clicks on the entire row?
I know i can get the id with:

```
mListView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
               view.delete.setOnClickListener(){
                   Toast.makeText(context,""+id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
              }
```

but this is working only if i click the entire row.
I tried `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the root of the xml and `android:focusable="false"` in the imageButton node, and the imageButton is not recognized anyway while the entire row is recognized. only if i using `button.onClickListener()...`
the click is recognized. but that way i don't know how to get the id.

my adapter class code:

```
class MyAdapter(activity: Activity, context: Context, cursor: Cursor) : CursorAdapter(context, cursor, true) {

    var inflater: LayoutInflater
    lateinit var mListView: ListView

    init {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mListView = activity.listView
    }

    override fun newView(context: Context?, cursor: Cursor?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false)

        return view;
    }
override fun bindView(view: View, context: Context, cursor: Cursor) {
        val latitude = view.findViewById(R.id.latitude) as TextView
        val longtitude = view.findViewById(R.id.longtitude) as TextView
        val date = view.findViewById(R.id.date) as TextView
        val asu = view.findViewById(R.id.asu) as TextView

        latitude.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.Signal.LATITUDE)))
        longtitude.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.Signal.LONGTITUDE)))
        date.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.Signal.DATE)))
        asu.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.Signal.ASU)))

    }
}
```

my single_row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latitude"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="latitude"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longtitude"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="longtitude"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/asu"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="asu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="0.23dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using cursor adapter, you should use ArrayAdapter.  [Here is why custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use](http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html)
and [example of ArrayAdapter](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)